# I want to develop a similar website like zomato using zomato API

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want to develop a similar website like zomato using the Zomato API to list down nearby restaurants based on name, cuisine or location, with an option to use the user’s current location.

I Know Javascript, JQuery, HTML5, CSS, BootStrap, AJAX languages.

Can anyone tell me how to get started with like say,
what framework should i use and how to start with.
Please help me with some kind of initiation.If you guys have any references please do share with me.Hoping for your help

Answer (score 0):

https://themeforest.net/
you may search from this site
I think from this site you find your need or help from this site.